# When exactly should I use the SQLite component in my Xamarin application?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, components

The Xamarin website shows two examples using SQLite, one does not use the SQLite built in Component and the other does use the SQLite Component. I am just wanting to see if anyone can explain the advantages/disadvantages. I am needing to create an Android application that display product catalogs for users based on different stores they visit. Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe post some snippets of the two different methods?

Comment: Without Component: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/  With Component: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite-component/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SQLite PCL Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/) from nuget.

It supports async operation and would not block your UI.

In my experience it is felt faster as well.

Also use the SQLite wrapper nuget if you don't want to reduce some lines of code. It helps you specify relationships.

Simple tutorial can be found [here](https://mcnextpost.com/2016/05/30/xamarin-using-sqlite-net-async-in-pcl/).

Comment: I highly recommend to use Frank Krueger's version of Sqlite.Net which is easier to use and more stable: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

Comment: Thank you very much Rohit, especially for including the tutorial. I will see what the boss says about this.